# Generating a unique node id for use with SQL Server hierarchyId

Tags: sql, common-table-expression, hierarchyid

**Setup :**

```
MyTable (
    NodeId varchar(10),
    ParentNodeId varchar(10),
    NodeName varchar(50)
)
```

NodeId is not numeric and can take any form. Majority are in the form Z123456 but some are 12345.

I want to use the SqlServer HierarchyId datatype for my hierarchical needs.

**Problem:**

I can use a CTE to generate my hierarchy with node and parent but i need a path to pass to hierarchyid::Parse() - unfortunately, a nodeid in the form Z123456 does not parse. If NodeId and ParentNodeId were row id integers I would be packing up and catching my train home to see my lovely wife, but instead, i'm here staring at a 3360 x 1050 resolution.

I am using a CTE to generate my hierarchy (and I can create a path within the CTE as well) and then afterward I attach the row number to give me my unique integer ids but i will then have to re-run the hierarchical CTE to generate my path using the generated Ids.

```
;with o as (
    select n.ParentNodeID, n.nodeid, n.NodeName, 1 as [level]
    from Mytable n where n.ParentNodeID is null
        union all
    select n.ParentNodeID, n.nodeid, n.NodeName, o.[level] + 1 as [Level]
    from MyTable n inner join o on n.ParentNodeID = o.NodeID
) 
select NodeID, ParentNodeID, NodeDescription
     , ROW_NUMBER() over (order by [level]) as hNodeId 
from o
```

**Question :**

Is there anyway I can achieve a path in a form hierarchyId::Parse() will accept with one CTE? e.g. /1/2/3/

TIA

Answer (score 3):

```
with C as
(
  select T.NodeId,
         T.ParentNodeId,
         cast('/'+cast(row_number() over(order by T.NodeId) as varchar(10)) as varchar(max)) as HID
  from MyTable as T
  where T.ParentNodeId is null
  union all
  select T.NodeId,
         T.ParentNodeId,
         C.HID+'/'+cast(row_number() over(order by T.NodeId) as varchar(10))
  from MyTable as T
    inner join C 
      on T.ParentNodeId = C.NodeId
)
select NodeId,
       ParentNodeId,
       HID,
       hierarchyId::Parse(HID+'/') 
from C
order by HID
```

[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b6daa3/2)

**Update:**
A bit of research show that using an analytical function in a recursive CTE is not permitted. It works in my tests but I will update this answer if I can think of an alternative solution.

[Omission about analytic and aggregate functions in CTEs](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/318084/omission-about-analytic-and-aggregate-functions-in-ctes)

**Update 2:**
Apparently this solution is safe to use since it is documented on MSDN.
[WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> Analytic and aggregate functions in the recursive part of the CTE are
>   applied to the set for the current recursion level and not to the set
>   for the CTE. Functions like ROW_NUMBER operate only on the subset of
>   data passed to them by the current recursion level and not the entire
>   set of data pased to the recursive part of the CTE

Comment: Thanks Mikael. I am doing some testing because my hierarchy is quite deep yielding a path like /1/1/1/1/1/1/1/1/12 - making sure I can get ancestors and descendants. One solution I was thinking of was doing a Select *, row_number() .. as row from MyTable into a CTE and then doing a recursive CTE on that using the 'row' column for the path but my recursive CTE is very slow (resultset is ~ 25000 rows). I will update when I have applied this logic to my code.

Comment: Don't do a recursive CTE using a CTE as the source of data. It is very slow because the first CTE (with the row_number) will be regenerated for each iteration. If you really need that it is better to use a temp table instead.

Comment: An index on ParentNodeId could speed things up a bit.